# How does item flipping work in RS3?

Tags: runescape

I've read [this article](https://runescape.wiki/w/Trading_and_merchanting_guide) on item flipping (specially the Types of merchanting was really interesting) but when I try to do some item flipping myself I tend to lose money every time! I've at this moment lost around 500 coins trying different items (first I would try one item then I would see if I could make profit) after trying around 20 different items (like iron bars, adamant arrows,feathers and coal ore for example) I haven't found any item that would make me profit.

I tried looking up which items where traded a lot on the [GE website](http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/top100?list=0) and found a few of the items there.

The problem is that I can't find an item to flip without losing money. Every item seems to sell for less than I'm buying it.

Is there a way to see what items tend to work for flipping?

Comment: This will also require patience.  Prices may go up or down as time goes on.  If they go down, you should hold onto your items.  Once they go back up, you'll have more success selling the item you bought for a profit.  The Wiki contains a graph for nearly every tradeable item and what the price was in the past for it as well as the current.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, there is a way to see which items are worth flipping:

1. You buy an Item for +10% of the current ge price.
2. You sell the Item for -10% of the current ge price.
3. Take a look at your ge history and write down those two values.
4. Buy the same item you've tested multiple times for (lower price + 5).
5. Sell the items for (higher price - 5).

If the two values at point number 3 have a too low difference, it is not worth to flip the item. The bigger the difference, the bigger your win.

Good Luck!

Comment: I know this but i never get any item that even makes a profit? I know how to flip but I don't know what items to use

Comment: i know this but I am not getting any profit on items only loses...

Comment: @BRHSM Keep trying and use the list of the most traded items. Minimize the buy-value to (lower price you've written down + 2) and sell the items for (higher price you've written down - 2).

Comment: @BRHSM Try it with runes, bars or logs. But don't expect a big win if your investment is small.

Comment: no succes... guess i'm gonna be making tipless arrows for a while